# How do I get button to save to console

Tags: button, local-storage

```html
<div class="card content-return">
<div class="card-image image">
<button  id="favoriteBtn">Save2Favorites</button>
```

[javascript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1Nue.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8cfL.png)

I’m a beginner and I’m having an issue getting my favoriteBtn to function when I click on it. Button doesn’t register in the console I get an error message in the console. What can I do? im using HTML and Javascript

Comment: Please add some details. What programming language are you using? What does your code look like?

Comment: Please provide a textual [mre]. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 0):

So, the structure of a HTML page is that the code should be written in between `<html>` tags.

Even if the tags aren't written, the browser will still render the file. As shown below.
[image: Image of code rendered as is]
In the above picture, you can see that even if the code in the text editor is the one which you gave in your question the browser still generated the `<html> and <body>` tags. **This maybe the error which you were talking about in your question**. Nothing to worry.

---

Given the code from your question, we will need to have some JS (JavaScript) code for the button to function. And we will be calling that function in the `onClick` attribute in our HTML button. Refer the below image.
[image: Image of Code with JS]

So, in the above code, we have added a method called `saveFavorites()` and we are calling it in our `onClick` attribute of our button.

---

**Note - Ignore the yellow messages in the console, those are just warnings.**

---

Posting the HTML Code Below -

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function saveFavorites(){
            alert("Button Clicked.");
        }
    </script>
</head>
    <body>
       <div class="card content-return">
                <div class="card-image image">
                    <button onclick="saveFavorites()" id="favoriteBtn">Save 2 Favorites</button>
                </div>
        </div> 
    </body>
</html>
```